# Why does increasing radiation frequency produce narrower collimated beams?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, laser, frequency

In the context of a THz Gaussian beam $(1)$, it is stated:

> Terahertz output radiation at higher frequency produced a narrower collimated beam owing
> to diffraction effects (...)

**What kind of diffraction effects cause higher radiation to produce narrower collimated beams?**

I'm more interested in an answer based on the diffraction effect, but mathematically this still makes no sense to me, because according to the formulas for the *Rayleigh range* and for the *spot size parameter* (respectively shown below),

$$z_R = \frac{\pi \omega_0^2 n}{\lambda} \tag{1}$$

$$w (z) = w_0 \sqrt{1+ \left( \frac{z}{z_R}\right)^2} \tag{2}$$

an increasing frequency should lead to a greater spot size.

**Where is this reasoning wrong?**

---

> 1. Broadband high-resolution terahertz single-pixel imaging. A.Vallés, J.He, S. Ohno, T.Omatsu, and K. Miyamoto. [*Opt. Express* **28**, 28868-28881,(2020)](https://doi.org/10.1364/OE.404143), [Opt. Express eprint](https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-28-20-28868&id=439587).

Answer (score 1):

Look also at the expression for divergence:

\begin{equation}
\theta=\frac{\lambda}{\pi w_0 }
\end{equation}

for 2 beams with the same waist $w_0$, the one with the lower wavelength (higher frequency) will also have a lower divergence.

With the equations you posted you can also see that 2 beams with the same waist, the Rayleigh range will be longer for that with the lowest wavelength (higher frequency).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, the math. The Rayleigh range $z_R = \pi w_0^2n/\lambda$ gets larger when the wavelength $\lambda$ gets smaller. So, increasing frequency makes for a larger $z_R$. Now, when we look at the waist formula,
$$w=w_0\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{z}{z_R}\right)^2}$$
we can see that a larger Rayleigh range will cause the beam to expand less for the same $z$.

As for the physical reason this happens, let me be a little hand-wavey. Think back to the double-slit experiment. Why is the central peak of long-wavelength light wider than short-wavelength light? It's because it takes larger path differences for two rays to destructively interfere due to the longer wavelength. It's the same with a coherent beam. It takes larger divergences from the beam axis for different parts of the long-wavelength wavefront to destructively interfere. This allows long wavelengths to diverge faster than short wavelengths.